# Hi I am making a card game I want to take input and select where the user wants to cut in cards and how can i do that?

Tags: java

```
package main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Ace", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = new String[13];
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = ranks[i] ;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        cutDeck(array);
        for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++ ) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
    public static String[] cutDeck(String[] deck) {
        System.out.println("Cut please. 'Choose between 1-51'");
        int cutPoint = scanner.nextInt();
        String[] topDeck= new String[52];
        String[] bottomDeck = new String[52];
        String[] newDeck = new String[deck.length];
        
        
        
        for (int i = 1; i<=cutPoint ; i++) {            // Topdeck
            topDeck[i-1] = deck[deck.length-1*i];
            
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cutPoint / 2; i++)           // Reverse topdeck 
        {
            String temp = topDeck[i];
            topDeck[i] = topDeck[topDeck.length - i - 1];
            topDeck[topDeck.length - i - 1] = temp;
        }
        
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i<deck.length - cutPoint; i++) {    //Bottom cut point
            bottomDeck[i] = deck[i];
    }
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i<deck.length; i++) {
            if (cutPoint > i) {
                newDeck[i] = topDeck[i];
            } else {
                newDeck[i] = bottomDeck[i];
            }
        }
        return newDeck;
}
    }
```

I am trying to cut the deck while asking to the user.

This function does not cut the deck.

Where am I doing wrong ?

I tried everything but I lost my brain can you guys help me please?

I am open to another ideas so you can give improve my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can see three obvious issues with this code:

The first issue is that the cutDeck method is not actually modifying the original deck array. Instead, it is creating a new array and returning it. In order to actually shuffle the original deck, you would need to modify the cutDeck method to modify the original array, rather than returning a new one.

Another issue is that the cutDeck method is currently assuming that the deck has 52 cards. However, the code in the main method is only creating an array with 13 cards. This means that the cutDeck method will not work properly with the deck created in main.

Finally, the code is currently hard-coding the number of cards in the deck as 52, and it is also assuming that the user will always enter a valid cut point when prompted. It would be better to make the code more flexible and robust by using the length of the input array to determine the number of cards in the deck, and also by checking that the user's input is within the valid range for the deck size.

An alternative way to do this would be:

```
public static void cutDeck(String[] deck) {
    System.out.println("Cut please. 'Choose between 1-" + (deck.length - 1) + "'");
    int cutPoint = scanner.nextInt();
    
    // Check that the cut point is within the valid range for the deck size
    if (cutPoint < 1 || cutPoint >= deck.length) {
        System.out.println("Invalid cut point. Please try again.");
        return;
    }
    
    // Create the top and bottom halves of the deck
    String[] topDeck = new String[cutPoint];
    String[] bottomDeck = new String[deck.length - cutPoint];
    for (int i = 0; i < cutPoint; i++) {
        topDeck[i] = deck[i];
    }
    for (int i = cutPoint; i < deck.length; i++) {
        bottomDeck[i - cutPoint] = deck[i];
    }
    
    // Reverse the top half of the deck
    for (int i = 0; i < cutPoint / 2; i++) {
        String temp = topDeck[i];
        topDeck[i] = topDeck[topDeck.length - i - 1];
        topDeck[topDeck.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    
    // Combine the top and bottom halves to create the shuffled deck
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
        if (i < cutPoint) {
            deck[i] = topDeck[i];
        } else {
            deck[i] = bottomDeck[i - cutPoint];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but i tried your code and the code is not working what i want because i need to cut from the top of the cards and I need to put it under other cards , like a real life

Comment: 4
3
2
5
6
7
8
9
10
Ace
Jack
Queen
King  not like this

Comment: king queen jack 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ace

Comment: like second one

Comment: you can alter the reversal function in the code I added to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

The loops in the O/P code can be replaced with existing methods in the [`Arrays` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) and the [`List` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) :

```
 public static String[] cut (String [] deck, int n) { 
     List<String> cutDeck = new ArrayList<> (deck.length);
     List<String> bottom = Arrays.asList (Arrays.copyOfRange (deck,n, deck.length));
     cutDeck.addAll (bottom);
     List<String> top = Arrays.asList (Arrays.copyOfRange (deck, 0, n));
     cutDeck.addAll (top);
     return cutDeck.toArray(deck);
 }
```

This assumes the `deck` is 1D array of `String`.  The test or other methods can call it like this:

```
 array = cut (array, cutPoint);
```

Note that this requires the value for `cutPoint` be set before calling the `cut` method. Moving the code to interact with the user to a different method makes the `cutDeck` method more cohesive, which is desirable.

Note that this does not reverse the order of cards in part of the deck. In real life, cutting a deck of cards does not reverse the order of part of the deck.  However, if reversing is desired, one way to do it is to add a call to the `reverse` method from [`Collections` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html)

```
     List<String> top = Arrays.asList (Arrays.copyOfRange (deck, 0, n));
     Collections.reverse(top);
     cutDeck.addAll (top);
```

As noted in the previous answer, `cutDeck(array);` in your code causes the shuffled deck result to be ignored. If you want to fix that part of your original code, change that line to `array = cutDeck(array);`

The other points in the first answer are also valid:

- You want to ensure the `cutPoint` value is valid.
- The `cutDeck`  method is more flexible if it gets the length to use from the array parameter.

By the way, the `Arrays` API has several `toString` methods. Using it can shorten code for printing array content, but with less control over formatting the output:

```
 System.out.println (Arrays.toString(array));
```

### Added: A simpler method:

As previously noted, in a real-life card game, cutting of the deck does not reverse the order of any of the cards. In fact, if you imagine the cards as a circular array, cutting the deck results in no change of order at all. Instead, it changes the starting point. Taking that into mind, we can write a single loop to cut the deck:

```
public static String[] cut2 (String [] deck, final int n) {
     String [] cutDeck = new String [deck.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < cutDeck.length; ++i) {
         cutDeck [i] = deck [ (i + n) % deck.length];
     }
     return cutDeck;
 }
```

Here is a test method:

```
 public static void cards () {
     String [] deck = {
               "two clubs", "three clubs", "four clubs"
             , "five clubs", "six clubs", "seven clubs"
             , "eight clubs", "nine clubs", "ten clubs"
             , "jack clubs", "queen clubs", "king clubs"
             , "ace clubs"
             , "two diamonds", "three diamonds", "four diamonds"
             , "five diamonds", "six diamonds", "seven diamonds"
             , "eight diamonds", "nine diamonds", "ten diamonds"
             , "jack diamonds", "queen diamonds", "king diamonds"
             , "ace diamonds"
             , "two hearts", "three hearts", "four hearts"
             , "five hearts", "six hearts", "seven hearts"
             , "eight hearts", "nine hearts", "ten hearts"
             , "jack hearts", "queen hearts", "king hearts"
             , "ace hearts"
             ," two spades", "three spades", "four spades"
             , "five spades", "six spades", "seven spades"
             , "eight spades", "nine spades", "ten spades"
             , "jack spades", "queen spades", "king spades"
             , "ace spades"
     };    
     
     System.out.println ("Original: " + Arrays.toString(deck));
     
     
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
         int r = (int) (Math.random () * deck.length);
         System.out.println ();
         System.out.println (r + " " + 
           Arrays.toString (cut  (Arrays.copyOf (deck, deck.length), r)));
         System.out.println (r + " " + 
           Arrays.toString (cut2 (Arrays.copyOf (deck, deck.length), r)));             
     }                                        
 }
```

The test method calls `cut` from above, and `cut2` from this part. If the call to `Collections.reverse` is not used in `cut`, then `cut` and `cut2` should return the same result.

Here is an example output from test run. Only the first three cuts are shown:

```
Original: [two clubs, three clubs, four clubs, five clubs, six clubs, seven clubs, eight clubs, nine clubs, ten clubs, jack clubs, queen clubs, king clubs, ace clubs, two diamonds, three diamonds, four diamonds, five diamonds, six diamonds, seven diamonds, eight diamonds, nine diamonds, ten diamonds, jack diamonds, queen diamonds, king diamonds, ace diamonds, two hearts, three hearts, four hearts, five hearts, six hearts, seven hearts, eight hearts, nine hearts, ten hearts, jack hearts, queen hearts, king hearts, ace hearts,  two spades, three spades, four spades, five spades, six spades, seven spades, eight spades, nine spades, ten spades, jack spades, queen spades, king spades, ace spades]

7 [nine clubs, ten clubs, jack clubs, queen clubs, king clubs, ace clubs, two diamonds, three diamonds, four diamonds, five diamonds, six diamonds, seven diamonds, eight diamonds, nine diamonds, ten diamonds, jack diamonds, queen diamonds, king diamonds, ace diamonds, two hearts, three hearts, four hearts, five hearts, six hearts, seven hearts, eight hearts, nine hearts, ten hearts, jack hearts, queen hearts, king hearts, ace hearts,  two spades, three spades, four spades, five spades, six spades, seven spades, eight spades, nine spades, ten spades, jack spades, queen spades, king spades, ace spades, two clubs, three clubs, four clubs, five clubs, six clubs, seven clubs, eight clubs]
7 [nine clubs, ten clubs, jack clubs, queen clubs, king clubs, ace clubs, two diamonds, three diamonds, four diamonds, five diamonds, six diamonds, seven diamonds, eight diamonds, nine diamonds, ten diamonds, jack diamonds, queen diamonds, king diamonds, ace diamonds, two hearts, three hearts, four hearts, five hearts, six hearts, seven hearts, eight hearts, nine hearts, ten hearts, jack hearts, queen hearts, king hearts, ace hearts,  two spades, three spades, four spades, five spades, six spades, seven spades, eight spades, nine spades, ten spades, jack spades, queen spades, king spades, ace spades, two clubs, three clubs, four clubs, five clubs, six clubs, seven clubs, eight clubs]

46 [nine spades, ten spades, jack spades, queen spades, king spades, ace spades, two clubs, three clubs, four clubs, five clubs, six clubs, seven clubs, eight clubs, nine clubs, ten clubs, jack clubs, queen clubs, king clubs, ace clubs, two diamonds, three diamonds, four diamonds, five diamonds, six diamonds, seven diamonds, eight diamonds, nine diamonds, ten diamonds, jack diamonds, queen diamonds, king diamonds, ace diamonds, two hearts, three hearts, four hearts, five hearts, six hearts, seven hearts, eight hearts, nine hearts, ten hearts, jack hearts, queen hearts, king hearts, ace hearts,  two spades, three spades, four spades, five spades, six spades, seven spades, eight spades]
46 [nine spades, ten spades, jack spades, queen spades, king spades, ace spades, two clubs, three clubs, four clubs, five clubs, six clubs, seven clubs, eight clubs, nine clubs, ten clubs, jack clubs, queen clubs, king clubs, ace clubs, two diamonds, three diamonds, four diamonds, five diamonds, six diamonds, seven diamonds, eight diamonds, nine diamonds, ten diamonds, jack diamonds, queen diamonds, king diamonds, ace diamonds, two hearts, three hearts, four hearts, five hearts, six hearts, seven hearts, eight hearts, nine hearts, ten hearts, jack hearts, queen hearts, king hearts, ace hearts,  two spades, three spades, four spades, five spades, six spades, seven spades, eight spades]

10 [queen clubs, king clubs, ace clubs, two diamonds, three diamonds, four diamonds, five diamonds, six diamonds, seven diamonds, eight diamonds, nine diamonds, ten diamonds, jack diamonds, queen diamonds, king diamonds, ace diamonds, two hearts, three hearts, four hearts, five hearts, six hearts, seven hearts, eight hearts, nine hearts, ten hearts, jack hearts, queen hearts, king hearts, ace hearts,  two spades, three spades, four spades, five spades, six spades, seven spades, eight spades, nine spades, ten spades, jack spades, queen spades, king spades, ace spades, two clubs, three clubs, four clubs, five clubs, six clubs, seven clubs, eight clubs, nine clubs, ten clubs, jack clubs]
10 [queen clubs, king clubs, ace clubs, two diamonds, three diamonds, four diamonds, five diamonds, six diamonds, seven diamonds, eight diamonds, nine diamonds, ten diamonds, jack diamonds, queen diamonds, king diamonds, ace diamonds, two hearts, three hearts, four hearts, five hearts, six hearts, seven hearts, eight hearts, nine hearts, ten hearts, jack hearts, queen hearts, king hearts, ace hearts,  two spades, three spades, four spades, five spades, six spades, seven spades, eight spades, nine spades, ten spades, jack spades, queen spades, king spades, ace spades, two clubs, three clubs, four clubs, five clubs, six clubs, seven clubs, eight clubs, nine clubs, ten clubs, jack clubs]
```